# (Proof) Proj. sum = V

Tags: vectors, linear-transformations

Great weekend guys, I got to a question here that I would like to know how can I prove in a way that It would be accepted in a test. 
[image]

Here is what I've got so far: 
[image]

Comment: What you have written seems perfectly acceptable to me, what makes you think it's not so?

Comment: @Shaktal The textbook that I am studying does not have the answer for the conceptual problems, and as a freshman I'm not really confident about my results at these ones.. But thank you!